# Flask streaming video

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm rendering a video. Not sure how skipping video to clicked time-frame works.

For example; I'm watching a video; but want to skip it to 10 minutes; how would I do that? It's not working right now because I do not have an API endpoint setup for it, or do I not need that?

```
<body>
  <video id="my-video" class="video-js" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264"
  poster="MY_VIDEO_POSTER.jpg" data-setup="{}">
    <source src="{{ url_for('testing', url=stream_url) }}" type='video/mp4'>
    <source src="MY_VIDEO.webm" type='video/webm'>
    <p class="vjs-no-js">
      To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that
      <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a>
    </p>
  </video>

  <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/6.6.3/video.js"></script>
</body>
```

I'm on flask.

```
@app.route('/streaming')
def testing():
     r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
     return Response(r.iter_content(30 * block_size),
                    content_type=r.headers['Content-Type'])
```

Right now when I click on my video and try an jump; it simply doesn't do anything.

Comment: This is probably going to involve way more work than you imagine.  It looks like you're essentially trying to implement an hls video transcoder. You might be able to tweak [this project](https://github.com/yvesf/flask-mediabrowser) to your needs if the video stream can be connected to with ffmpeg... That project may or may not even work, to begin with though.

Comment: @sytech So how would ffmpeg work? I would first have to download the video file fully; then only I'd be able to tweak with it? Or is it possible to do that while using python-requests?

Comment: ffmpeg should be able to connect to a video stream -- You would stop using `requests` altogether and delegate that work to ffmpeg.

Comment: Okay, so I'm assuming I can use ffmpeg tweak files on memory(with a url) without actually saving it on my disk, right?